# Noise suppression almost completely muting my microphone

Tags: windows-10, microphone, asus-laptop, noise-cancelling

Everything was fine, but I noticed my microphone almost had no volume one day. The problem is noise cancellation. IDK why, but it suddenly started working really weirdly, instead of noise-canceling it just mutes my microphone almost completely. It's about a built-in microphone.

Asus Vivobook Pro 15 
Windows 10

Noise-canceling here is `Single presenter conference call` and `Multi-presenter conference call` in `Microphone Effects`:
[image: Settings]

When I turn on either of these options my microphone became almost not audible, but a few days ago they worked fine.

Comment: Your description: " It's about a built-in microphone,." i.e., one mic. The settings you're changing are for **an array of microphones,**, i.e., 2 or more. What are the settings fo *Microphone*?

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik this "Microphone" is the microphone from my headset (when I take out the cable it disappears). It has no special settings. I believe "Microphone array" refers only to the built-in mic."

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the way your eyes capture a stereo image to give depth perception, array microphones use multiple mics to detect audio source position.

Those options simple restrict the angle at which the mic with allow audio from.
Single presenter will be a narrow detection field, i.e a single user sitting in front of the laptop. Mult-presenter will be a wider field.

As to why it has stopped working recently.. Perhaps you've changed you seating position and are slightly of axis to where the mic expects?